# Calculating who is about to turn 3 years of age in SPSS

Tags: spss

I would like to determine who is about to turn 3 years of age in SPSS code.  How can this best be done?  The two ways I crafted  were:

1.

```
compute Almost3Age = ((xdate.tday($time) - xdate.tday(dobmtu))/365.25).

compute Almost3 = 0.
if Almost3Age ge 2.91 and Almost3Age lt 3 Almost3 = 1.
```

**********************OR*********************************
2.

```
compute Almost3 = 0.
if (xdate.year($time) - xdate.year(dobmtu) eq 3) and (xdate.month($time) = xdate.month(dobmtu)
   and xdate.mday($time) lt xdate.mday(dobmtu)) Almost3 = 1.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only problem with your code is that it does not take into account different length months.

I need to know who is 2 years and 11 months old.
I don't want to cut out anyone that will turn 3 exactly a month from today, so i'll take today's date, subtract a day, and calculate 2yrs and 11 months variable.

if you don't want to include people turning 3 today...

```
compute twoyears11months=datedif(datesum($time,-1,'days'),dobmtu,'months').
select if twoyears11months =35.
```

otherwise, exclude bday today and in one line.

```
select if datedif($time,dobmtu,'months') =35.
```